# T-SQL How to pull previous row regardless of the entered parameters

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, parameters, sql-server-2014

I am working on a report that prints readmit patients' visits information.

The T-SQL query prints the repeat visits based on an `IIF` statement (using `LEAD` and `LAG`) that looks to see if there is a visit within 30 days of the visit's admit date for the same patient - and simply says 1 for Yes, 0 for No (AS 'ReadmittedFilter'), and when no parameters are entered I can see all of the data as expected. Query is as follows:

```
,IIF(   (IIF(((xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LEAD(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber) 
        AND xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LAG(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber))
        AND ((DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(RART.RegistrationTypeDischargeDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),RAM.AdmitDateTime) BETWEEN 0 AND 30))),
        DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(RART.RegistrationTypeDischargeDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),RAM.AdmitDateTime),0) 

        = IIF(((xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LEAD(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber) 
        AND xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LAG(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber))
        AND ((DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(RART.RegistrationTypeDischargeDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),RAM.AdmitDateTime) BETWEEN 0 AND 30))),
        DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(RART.RegistrationTypeDischargeDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),RAM.AdmitDateTime), 0)) 

    AND (IIF(((xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LEAD(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber) 
    OR xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LAG(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber))
    AND ((DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(RART.RegistrationTypeDischargeDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),RAM.AdmitDateTime) BETWEEN 0 AND 30))),

DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(RART.RegistrationTypeDischargeDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),RAM.AdmitDateTime),
DATEDIFF(DAY,RART.RegistrationTypeDischargeDateTime, LEAD(RAM.AdmitDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber))) BETWEEN 0 AND 30),

1,0) AS 'ReadmittedFilter'
```

I am inserting all of the data `INTO #tblTempCalculations` and then I do

```
SELECT *  
FROM #tblTempCalculations 
WHERE #tblTempCalculations.ReadmittedFilter = 1
```

printing only patients who have 1 in 'ReadmittedFilter'

However, once I add date ranges (or any other parameters), in many cases, they remove the previous visit from the printout. What I am trying to achieve is to force print the patient's previous visit even if it does not fit under the entered parameters, and have the parameters apply only to the current visit.

I have the query saved into a stored procedure, and I produce reports with different parameters on SSRS 2014 side.

For example

No parameters currently:

```
Patient    VisitID  AdmitDate  DischargeDate PrevDisDate DaysBtwnVisits
John Doe   10001    10/1/13    10/5/13       NULL        NULL 
John Doe   10014    10/7/13    10/10/13      10/5/13     2
Jean All   10003    10/2/13    10/6/13       NULL        NULL
Jean All   10018    10/11/13   10/17/13      10/6/13     5
Jane Smith 10035    11/1/13    11/4/13       NULL        NULL
Jane Smith 10042    11/22/13   11/25/13      11/4/13     18
```

With parameters currently:

- `@FromDischargeDate = '10/10/13'`
- `@ThroughDischargeDate = '10/30/13'`

Output:

```
Patient   VisitID  AdmitDate  DischargeDate PrevDisDate DaysBtwnVisits
John Doe  10004    10/7/13    10/10/13      10/5/13     2
Jean All  10018    10/11/13   10/17/13      10/6/13     5
```

How I need it work with parameters:

- `@FromDischargeDate = '10/10/13'`
- `@ThroughDischargeDate = '10/30/13'`

Output:

```
Patient   VisitID  AdmitDate  DischargeDate PrevDisDate DaysBtwnVisits
John Doe  10001    10/1/13    10/5/13       NULL        NULL 
John Doe  10004    10/7/13    10/10/13      10/5/13     2
Jean All  10003    10/2/13    10/6/13       NULL        NULL
Jean All  10018    10/11/13   10/17/13      10/6/13     5
```

Please let me know if more information is needed to look into this.

Thank you.

Dq

Edit 4 - The [final working] query:

```
    ;WITH xxUnitNumber (UnitNumber,VisitID,SourceID) AS 
        (SELECT 
        CASE RAM.Facility_MisFacID
        WHEN 'LOA' THEN (Select HRMRN.PrefixMedicalRecordNumber from livefdb.dbo.HimRec_MedicalRecordNumbers HRMRN where RAM.SourceID = HRMRN.SourceID and RAM.PatientID = HRMRN.PatientID and HRMRN.MrnPrefixID = 'LO') 
        WHEN 'LUA' THEN (Select HRMRN.PrefixMedicalRecordNumber from livefdb.dbo.HimRec_MedicalRecordNumbers HRMRN where RAM.SourceID = HRMRN.SourceID and RAM.PatientID = HRMRN.PatientID and HRMRN.MrnPrefixID = 'LU') 
        ELSE NULL END,RAM.VisitID,RAM.SourceID
        FROM [livefdb].[dbo].[RegAcct_Main] RAM)

SELECT  
    RAM.AccountNumber
    ,xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber
    ,RAM.AdmitDateTime
    ,RART.RegistrationTypeDischargeDateTime AS 'DischargeDateTime'
    ,IIF(   (IIF(((xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LEAD(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber) 
            AND xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LAG(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber))
            AND ((DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(RART.RegistrationTypeDischargeDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),RAM.AdmitDateTime) BETWEEN 0 AND 30))),
            DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(RART.RegistrationTypeDischargeDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),RAM.AdmitDateTime),0) 

            = IIF(((xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LEAD(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber) 
            AND xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LAG(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber))
            AND ((DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(RART.RegistrationTypeDischargeDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),RAM.AdmitDateTime) BETWEEN 0 AND 30))),
            DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(RART.RegistrationTypeDischargeDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),RAM.AdmitDateTime), 0)) 

        AND (IIF(((xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LEAD(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber) 
        OR xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LAG(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber))
        AND ((DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(RART.RegistrationTypeDischargeDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),RAM.AdmitDateTime) BETWEEN 0 AND 30))),

    DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(RART.RegistrationTypeDischargeDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),RAM.AdmitDateTime),
    DATEDIFF(DAY,RART.RegistrationTypeDischargeDateTime, LEAD(RAM.AdmitDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber))) BETWEEN 0 AND 30),

    1,0) AS 'ReadmittedFilter'

    ,IIF(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LAG(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(RART.RegistrationTypeDischargeDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),RAM.AdmitDateTime),IIF(IIF(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LEAD(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber) OR xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LAG(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),NULL) >= 1,0,NULL)) 'Days'
    ,IIF(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LEAD(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber) OR xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LAG(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),NULL) AS 'VisitCount'
    ,IIF(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber = LAG(xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),LAG(RART.RegistrationTypeDischargeDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber),NULL) AS 'PrevDisDate'


INTO #tblTempCalculations

    FROM [livefdb].[dbo].[RegAcct_Main] RAM 
    INNER JOIN livefdb.dbo.RegAcct_RegistrationTypes RART ON RART.SourceID = RAM.SourceID AND RART.VisitID = RAM.VisitID AND RART.RegistrationTypeKey_MisRegTypeID = 'IN'
    INNER JOIN xxUnitNumber ON xxUnitNumber.VisitID = RAM.VisitID AND xxUnitNumber.SourceID = RAM.SourceID

    WHERE       RAM.SourceID = 'LOF'
    AND     RAM.ServiceInpatient_MisSvcID NOT IN ('REH','SNF')
    AND     RAM.Location_MisLocID NOT IN ('LO MB',' LO NB','LO SCN1')

    ORDER BY xxUnitNumber.UnitNumber, RAM.AccountNumber

    SELECT 
*
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY #tblTempCalculations.UnitNumber ORDER BY #tblTempCalculations.UnitNumber, #tblTempCalculations.AccountNumber DESC) as 'VisitRowCount'
```

INTO #tblTempCalculations2

```
FROM #tblTempCalculations 

WHERE 
#tblTempCalculations.UnitNumber IN (SELECT UnitNumber FROM #tblTempCalculations WHERE #tblTempCalculations.ReadmittedFilter = 1 AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), #tblTempCalculations.DischargeDateTime, 111) BETWEEN @FromDischargeDate AND @ThroughDischargeDate)
 AND #tblTempCalculations.Facility = @Facility      

ORDER BY #tblTempCalculations.UnitNumber, #tblTempCalculations.AccountNumber

SELECT *
FROM #tblTempCalculations2
WHERE #tblTempCalculations2.VisitRowCount < 3
ORDER BY #tblTempCalculations2.UnitNumber, #tblTempCalculations2.AccountNumber

DROP TABLE #tblTempCalculations
DROP TABLE #tblTempCalculations2
```

Comment: And what is the magic difference between result without parameters and desired result with parameters?

Comment: It is hard to troubleshoot why your output is returning incorrectly without seeing any of the sql used to get the data as presented. Off hand, I would recommend that if you have an ID that is unique to the patient (remains the same over multiple visits) that you do a select from a subset where the discharge date is between the parameter dates. for instance: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE PatientID IN (SELECT PatientID FROM TABLE WHERE DischargeDate BETWEEN @FromDischargeDate AND @ThroughDischargeDate)`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I added 2 more entries to the result without parameters for more clarity against what is needed.

Comment: @JeffBeese Thank you, however, wouldn't it still limit the output by the entered DischargeDate? You are correct, I have a UnitNumber that I use to separate one patient from another. In essence, the sql code I have pulls all of the needed fields, the actual filtering of the readmits is done through 1 calculation, which I included above (ReadmittedFilter). Please let me know if more information is needed. I apologize if I misunderstand something, as I am new to sql.

Comment: No, only the inner select (which is not where your records are coming from) would limit the records to those between the discharge dates. Selecting the records from your main table, where there is a UnitNumber in the query that limits the records to just those between the discharge dates will return all of a patients records where they have a discharge date within the range. You will want to do something along the lines of: `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE UnitNumber IN (SELECT UnitNumber FROM YourTable Where DischargeDate BETWEEN @FromDischargeDate AND @ThroughDischargeDate)`

Comment: If you can provide some of the text of your query, I would be able to provide you with a better example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 2 UnitNumber,
       Patient,   
       VisitID,  
       AdmitDate,  
       DischargeDate, 
       PrevDisDate, 
       DaysBtwnVisits  
FROM #tblTempCalculations AS T1
WHERE T1.ReadmittedFilter = 1 AND
      T1.UnitNumber IN
      (SELECT UnitNumber
       FROM #tblTempCalculations AS T2
       WHERE DischargeDate BETWEEN @FromDischargeDate AND @ThroughDischargeDate)
ORDER BY DischargeDate DESC
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff, I added this into the query and it appears to be close to what is needed. However, it now pulls many more visits for the UnitNumber going back multiple years, instead of just 1 previous visit. I will add the entire query as it is right now to my original post.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. I applied your suggestion it almost brought everything together. I just moved the ReadmittedFilter into the subquery and it started filtering everything as needed - I updated my original question with the final version of the query.